# How do I set representations properly in .vmdrc for VMD

Tags: vmd

I'm trying to setup default representations on load, and currently have added the following to the default .vmdrc file.

```
display depthcue off
color Display Background white
display projection orthographic
mol default color {index}
mol default style {CPK 1.0 12 0.3 12}
mol default selection {all}
menu main move 62 1236
menu graphics move 166 1477
```

I have also tried this line:

```
mol default style CPK
```

And variations on the selection command, such as {name A}, since I'm using hoomd and A type particles, but all to no avail, it ignores the representation style and color settings no matter what I do, but the other settings work just fine. Anyone able to help me figure out why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the molecule not being read into vmd upon startup (at the time of your .vmdrc file being read). I suspect you start vmd from command line with "vmd molecule.file" rather than opening up vmd first, then loading in the molecule from the File > New Molecule tab. If you do it the former way, then your "mol" instructions in the .vmdrc file are being applied to a non-existent molecule. The latter should work with the commands you've provided.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208971/default-representation-drawing-method-in-vmd) for how to get these defaults working for you with a command line startup.